# Drawing N balls from an Urn. Probability I have the represenative proportion of balls

Tags: probability, statistics, sampling

I have a urn full of M balls with an unknown mix of white and black balls.  I draw N balls out (without replacement) and get a particular proportion of white vs black balls.  From the looks of it there should be a way for my to calculate the probability the balls I have draw have the same proportion (white vs black) as the balls in the urn.

Am I also able to calculate the probabilities of the various proportions based on what what I've draw?

For example if I have a urn full of 10 balls and I draw out 5 white balls then it would be very unlikely the initial composition of the urn would be 5 white/5 black.

Comment: With replacement or without? Usually in this sort of problem, we have a *prior* distribution, that is, a distribution for the number of each kind. Uniform prior can be used, but it is not necessarily the most appropriate prior. Then, using our experimental result, we can find the *posterior* distribution.

Comment: Clarified that there is no replacement.  However the prior is unknown.

Comment: Without a prior, classical conditional probability has nothing to offer.

Comment: Can you explain why?  I can enumerate all possible urns and all possible draws from that urn with a perticular proportion and then count the number of situations where the two are the same.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are. You're missing the fact that counting the number of favourable situations only allows you to calculate a probability if all situations are equiprobable. Since you don't know the prior, you don't know that they are.

Comment: In effect, you thought of the equiprobable prior as the natural one. I don't think it necessarily is, but if you want to specify it, certainly we can compute, it is a "Bayes' Rule" calculation.